# The android studio AVD emulator does not show my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I finished a simple app I learned how to do from "Android Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd Edition)" the app does nothing but ask a question and wait for an answer and then display weather the answer is correct or not, in a toast.

So I finished the app but when I run it on the android studio AVD emulator I see nothing bu the empty home screen

I am new to android (in fact this is my first app ever) so I don't really know a lot, most of the code is auto generated but I understand some of it but I can't edit it:

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text"></TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the java code (all of it except the onCreate method is auto generated:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The string resource xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="question_text">Constantinople is the largest city in Turkey.</string>
    <string name="true_button">True</string>
    <string name="false_button">False</string>
    <string name="correct_toast">Correct !</string>
    <string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrect !</string>
</resources>
```

And everything else is auto generated and not modefied, screenshots:

[the android emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5IEH.png)

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d2Bo.png)

Comment: What does your `AndroidManifest.xml` file look like? Based on what you have completed it looks like you just finished Ch 2. Move ahead to Ch3 and read about logcat. Then provide us your logcat output. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try starting the emulator first and then run the project. It will prompt you to choose a device since the device is up and running select it and see if it will help.

Comment: tried that it prompts me for the device and i choose the running one but nothing happens after that.

Comment: i should point out that my computer has 3 GB of RAM and the emulator is really slow

Comment: If RAM is an issue try using an real android device. My PC has 2GB of RAM but using a  real device saves my day. Hope u have one?

Comment: I just bought a new laptop and it works perfectly in it but thanks for the help anyway.